# Dynamic Linq gives error in combination with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

We use Entity Framework, and we need some runtime build queries on our objects. Building expression trees from scratch seems like a lot of work, so we want to use "System.Linq.Dynamic"

Working through the samples I got this to work:

`dbModel.As.Where("AStuff.Contains(@0) OR AStuff.Contains(@1)","ac","bc")`

But if I try to build the expressions seperately like this:

```
    Expression<Func<A, bool>> predicateA =
        DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<A, bool>(                    
            "AStuff.Contains(@0)",
            "ac"
        );

    Expression<Func<A,bool>> predicateB =
        DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<A, bool>(
            "AStuff.Contains(@0)",
            "bc"
        );

    dbModel.As.Where("@0(it) OR @1(it)", predicateA, predicateB);
```

it explodes with an exception:
NotSupportedException>>The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

It may be possible to build the entire query in the first form, but the later would be more useful in our scenario. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: What's the goal here? Do you think expression trees are simpler or easier to maintain than SQL?

Comment: @Andomar: Build dynamic linq in modular fashion. no, Dynamic SQL is much easier to build in these cases, but for many other reasons we use EF and Linq. So I would like to stick to this  Linq EF "flavor" in my solution. I think Linq is lacking here: dynamic linq should be no harder than dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to join (Or/And) multiple predicates.

Comment: Thanks, but but it worries me that i'm getting further and further away from a "parse this string to Linq" solution, which was so easy to do in the SQL days... I hope MS will do some work on this in the future